# How to copy text from nano (ssh tmux) to gui editor in local computer

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have already activated the mouse with `set -g mouse on` in `.tmux.conf`.

This works inside tmux. But how do I copy to and from outside tmux?

[Copy text from one tmux pane to another (using vim)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/copy-text-from-one-tmux-pane-to-another-using-vim)

This works only in one terminal output buffer

[Copy text from remote tmux to local x clipboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572874/copy-text-from-remote-tmux-to-local-x-clipboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold shift+mouse to copy selection